# Swap Rubiks Cube Corners Diagonally Across

Tags: rubiks-cube

My cube has ended up in a position where I need to swap the corners diagonally across to finish the cube. However to my understanding this is impossible. Is there another way to solve this? I tried taking the cube apart but the corner pieces are stuck on this particular one. Note that it is the [Ghost Cube Black](https://www.cubelelo.com/ghost-cube-black) variant. Help me, thank you.

Comment: If you can, could you please provide a picture? But, most importantly, *don't take the cube apart* — *that's cheating!*

Comment: @user477343 It's not cheating if someone else took it apart to "stack the cube" against you. See [gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting).

Comment: @Chowzen Well, that still is cheating — on *their* part. Besides, why would someone do that? Imagine your mind going through all this trauma to solve the Rubiks cube to then tell yourself, *hang on, this is impossible to achieve*. But I mean, that would be me, because I don't know any Rubiks cube algorithms, and I like to solve it on my own. (Two sides completed at the same time is my record.) Unless the whole "gaslighting" idea is just a fun game.

Comment: `I tried taking the cube apart but the corner pieces are stuck on this particular one.` .... what does this mean?   .... if it means that you are unable to take the cube apart, then say that you are unable to take it apart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-pasted my comment as an answer on request of *@Rubio♦*:

> There are two pair of pieces that are very similar on the Ghost Cube,
>   so you've probably swapped those pieces by accident causing the issues
>   with the last two corners you have now. I don't know which brand of
>   Ghost Cube you have, but make sure everything you've already solved is
>   completely flat. Most likely one of those triangle-shaped corners are
>   swapped (that's usually the case when I solve [mine](http://s8.postimg.cc/qq5945vf9/DSC_0036.jpg)). But it's also
>   possible the three (corner-edge-corner) that are similar are all
>   swapped together.
>   <sup>[link to comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68251/swap-rubics-cube-corners-diagonally-across?noredirect=1#comment205123_68251)</sup>

Pictures (of each of the six sides of the Ghost Cube) would help, though. That way we might be better able to pin-point the problem.

Comment: Aha so damn sneaky

Answer (score 1):

If the corners are stuck in place, I would try solving the cube working from the corners rather then trying to move the corners.